# python and imaplib: how to download attachments given uid

Tags: python, imaplib

How can I download the attachments given that I have already got the email uids that I want to download?

Can someone give me some code that I can refer to?

As I do some research, I think I should use `FETCH` in the syntax like: `mail.uid('fetch', uid, 'message_set')`. So what should be the `message_set` if I want to get the attachment? Or correct me if I am not on the right track.